# Childnode to Object using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to transform the following `XML` code to an object using JQuery.
This is how my XML looks:

```
<league name="German 1st Bundesliga>
    <club name="FC Bayern München"          coach="Ancelotti"   stadium="Allianz Arena"     clubId="1000" />
    <club name="Borussia Dortmund"          coach="Tuchel"      stadium="Signal Iduna Park" clubId="1001" />
    <club name="Borussia Mönchengldabach"   coach="Schubert"    stadium="Borussia-Park"     clubId="1002" />
    <club name="FC Schlke 04"               coach="Weinzierl"   stadium="Veltins-Arena"     clubId="1003" />
 </league>
```

This is my code to create the object

```
var $leagueNode = $(response).find('league');   

var clubList = [];

for(var i=0; i < $leagueNode.children().length; i++){
    console.log($leagueNode.children()[i]);
    var $clubNode = $($leagueNode.children()[i]).find('club');              
    var club = {};
    club.clubid = $clubNode.attr('clubid');
    club.name = $clubNode.attr('name');
    club.coach = $clubNode.attr('coach');
    club.stadium= $clubNode.attr('stadium');
    console.log(club);
}
```

The object printed to the console shows `undefined` for all attributes. What is wrong with my code?

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work". What is the problem?

Comment: @sudomakeinstall2 changed that in the question

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I just want to create a common object in JS, I corrected that.

Comment: http://goessner.net/download/prj/jsonxml/    can use this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do what you require you can use `map()` to create an array of objects. Try this:

```js
var $leagueNode = $('<league name="German 1st Bundesliga"><club name="FC Bayern München" coach="Ancelotti" stadium="Allianz Arena" clubId="1000" /><club name="Borussia Dortmund" coach="Tuchel" stadium="Signal Iduna Park" clubId="1001" /><club name="Borussia Mönchengldabach" coach="Schubert" stadium="Borussia-Park" clubId="1002" /><club name="FC Schlke 04" coach="Weinzierl" stadium="Veltins-Arena" clubId="1003" /></league>');
var obj = $leagueNode.find('club').map(function() {
  var $club = $(this);
  return {
    clubid: $club.attr('clubid'),
    name: $club.attr('name'),
    coach: $club.attr('coach'),
    stadium: $club.attr('stadium'),
  };
}).get();

console.log(obj);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```